# In R, how do I access information in a data set using a variable after the $?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, bioconductor

I'm using Bioconductor to look at GO terms. I can use for instance GOBPANCESTOR$"GO:0060412" to get all the ancestral terms to 0060412. However, I need to loop through many possible terms. However, I can't seem to get GOBPANCESTOR$ to accept a variable after the $.

```
 > GOBPANCESTOR$"GO:0060412"
 [1] "GO:0003007" "GO:0003205" "GO:0003206" "GO:0003231" "GO:0003279"     "GO:0003281" "GO:0007275" "GO:0009653" "GO:0009887" "GO:0007507" "GO:0008150"
[12] "GO:0032501" "GO:0032502" "GO:0044699" "GO:0044707" "GO:0044767" "GO:0048513" "GO:0048731" "GO:0048856" "GO:0060411" "GO:0072358" "GO:0072359"
[23] "all"
```

But...

```
> mygoterm <- "GO:0060412"
> GOBPANCESTOR$mygoterm

 NULL
```

Also tried using paste to no avail. I feel like I must be misunderstanding something integral about the way R works...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't. You use [[ instead.

Comment: oh my gosh... i feel like such an idiot. Thank you, solved my problem.